# Select to end of line in phpstorm

Tags: macos, phpstorm

I want to select the text from current position to end of the line with keyboard shortcuts in phpstorm (mac OS). What is the shortcut?

Also I want to select the text from current position to next word with keyboard shortcuts in phpstorm (mac OS). What is the shortcut?

I checked the reference guide in here, but I could not find these shortcuts:
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/PhpStorm_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not specific to phpStorm, but are system wide on MacOS X

End of line: **cmd+shift+left-arrow**

**option+shift+left-arrow** selects to end of a word, press again for next word.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Shift+End** to select a line to the end if the cursor is in the beginning of the line.

Similarly, Use **Shift+Home** to select a line to the beginning if the cursor is in the end of the line.